# Proc hpbin with minimum proportion per bin

Tags: sas, nested-loops, binning, sas-studio

I am using Proc HPBIN to split my data into equally-spaced buckets i.e. each bucket has an equal proportion of the total range of the variable.

My issue is when I have extremely skewed data with a large range. Almost all of my datapoints lie in one bucket while there is a couple of observations scattered around the extremes.

I'm wondering if there is a way to force PROC HPBIN to consider the proportion of values in each bin and make sure there is at least e.g. 5% of observations in a bin and to group others?

```
DATA var1;
    DO VAR1 = 1 TO 100;
        OUTPUT;
    END;
    DO VAR1 = 500 TO 505;
        OUTPUT;
    END;
    DO VAR1 = 7000 TO 7015;
        OUTPUT;
    END;
    DO VAR1 = 1000000 TO 1000010;
        OUTPUT;
    END;
RUN;

/*Use proc hpbin to generate bins of equal width*/
ODS EXCLUDE ALL;
ODS OUTPUT
    Mapping = bin_width_results;
PROC HPBIN
    DATA=var1
    numbin = 15
    bucket;
    input VAR1 / numbin = 15;
RUN;
ODS EXCLUDE NONE;
```

Id like to see a way that proc hpbin or other method groups together the bins which are empty and allows at least 5% of proportion per bucket. However, I am not looking to use percentiles in this case (it is another plot on my pdf) because I'd see like to see the spread.

Comment: Would 1 bin containing 100% of the data qualify as *at least 5%*

Answer (score 1):

`Quantile` option and `20` bins should give you ~5% per bin

```
PROC HPBIN DATA=var1 quantile;
    input VAR1 / numbin = 20;
RUN;
```

When the values of a bin need to be dynamically rebinned due overly high proportions in a bin (problem bins) you need to `hpbin` only those values in the problem bins.  A macro can be written to loop around the `HPBIN` process, zooming in on problem areas.

For example:

```
DATA have;
    DO VAR1 = 1 TO 100;
        OUTPUT;
    END;
    DO VAR1 = 500 TO 505;
        OUTPUT;
    END;
    DO VAR1 = 7000 TO 7015;
        OUTPUT;
    END;
    DO VAR1 = 1000000 TO 1000010;
        OUTPUT;
    END;
RUN;

%macro bin_zoomer (data=, var=, nbins=, rezoom=0.25, zoomlimit=8, out=);

  %local data_view step nextstep outbins zoomers;

  proc sql;
    create view data_zoom1 as
    select 1 as step, &var from &data;
  quit;

  %let step = 1;
  %let data_view = data_zoom&step;
  %let outbins = bins_step&step;

%bin:
  %if &step > &zoomlimit %then %goto done;

  ODS EXCLUDE ALL;
  ODS OUTPUT Mapping = &outbins;
  PROC HPBIN DATA=&data_view bucket ;
    id step;
    input &var / numbin = &nbins;
  RUN;
  ODS EXCLUDE NONE;

  proc sql noprint;
    select count(*) into :zoomers trimmed
    from &outbins
    where proportion >= &rezoom
  ;

  %put NOTE: &=zoomers;

  %if &zoomers = 0 %then %goto done;

  %let step = %eval(&step+1);

  proc sql;
    create view data_zoom&step as
    select &step as step, *
    from &data_view data
    join &outbins   bins
    on data.&var between bins.LB and bins.UB
       and bins.proportion >= &rezoom
    ;
  quit;

  %let outbins = bins_step&step;
  %let data_view = data_zoom&step;

  %goto bin;

%done:

  %put NOTE: done @ &=step;

  * stack the bins that are non-problem or of final zoom;
  * the LB to UB domains from step2+ will discretely cover the bounds
  * of the original step1 bins;
  data &out;
    set 
      bins_step1-bins_step&step
      indsname = source
    ;
    if proportion < &rezoom or source = "bins_step&step";
    step = source;
  run;

%mend;

options mprint;

%bin_zoomer(data=have, var=var1, nbins=15, out=bins);
```

Comment: I imagine this is the same as percentiles (quantiles giving an equal-ish number of observations per bin) My thoughts are that I still want to have an equal width per bin it's just that the extremes are grouped together such that I essentially zoom in on that bin with 90% of observations in it. I.e. I want to see the distribution of the obs in that bin

Comment: If you zoom in on a particular domain to see the distribution within a bin the bin size changes.  If you have a fixed number of bins the proportion in each bin will vary; and you can know what the proportion is via the output data.  You would need a second step to identify the domains (bins) you want to zoom into and have additional criteria on how to break those bins into finer detail, again with fixed # of bins or quantiles.

Comment: I thought so, I will get to work on this. I am reading your answer, I am going to test it out!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `WINSOR` method (winsorised binning)?  From the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/prochp/67530/HTML/default/viewer.htm#prochp_hpbin_overview02.htm):

> Winsorized binning is similar to bucket binning except that both tails are cut off to obtain a smooth binning result. This technique is often used to remove outliers during the data preparation stage.

You can specify the `WINSORRATE` to impact how it adjusts these tails.

Comment: I will look into this! I am already removing 5% of the data by trimming the percentiles. However, some of my factors are ratios which become unstable when the denominator is small

Comment: This makes it more a data quality issue but difficult to manage